# Blur view on previous VC in the navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, blur

I have VC 1. From it I present VC 2. The VC 2 have bottom part with tableView and top part is clear, and thought it I can see VC 1. It works correctly.

Now I need to add blur effect to top clear area of VC 2.
I made this using `UIVisualEffect`

My code:

```
 UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]; 
 UIVisualEffectView *blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
```

It works, but I need to change our color to some custom. There si not such capabilities in `UIVisualEffect`. So I need some other solution.

How can I do it?

I tried to make it with `FXBlur`, but then problem here I guess  in that I can not blur view from VC 1 adding blur in VC 2.

Now I think that I can make screenshot of VC 1's view, send it to VC 2, set it to `imageView` and then blur `imageView` with custom color.

But I think that status bar will not display actual time as it will be an image. How can I do this blur, maybe there is more smart solution? Because I do not like that I need send screenshot through `ViewControllers`

Comment: You can just add a UIView below the blur view in the z-order and set its background color to your tint with some acceptable alpha.

Comment: I need to use VC because there are some logic in it

Comment: The blur view (FXBlur) do not blurs views from other VC rather then it visible